# Internal secondary HDD disappeared (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, asus-laptop

Hello and thanks in advance for your help.

I have a ~2 year old Asus G501JW laptop with a main SSD storage of 100Gb and 2 secondary HDDs of 500Gb (those are the default drives).

From time to time, both secondary HDDs suddenly disappeared after coming out of sleep mode, but they always returned when I hard booted the computer. Aside from that the computer worked perfectly.

Yesterday the same happened again, but now they don't reappear when I hard boot. I have looked for them in both the device manager and the disk manager and cannot find them there either.

I tried plugging it off and leaving it for 30 minutes (could not take the battery off because it is inside the computer), and nothing changed.

I think the hard drives don't show in BIOS, but I am not completely sure.
Pictures of where I looked: https://ibb.co/gsxYPH, https://ibb.co/j45L4H

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to check if they show up in your bios, also have you tried removing the power, and the battery, leaving the laptop for 15 minutes then booting it back up? - Once you've checked, edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

You should review that you can see the disk on the BIOS.

These are the instructions for accessing to the BIOS with ASUS on Windows 10.

https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1013015/#

If you can´t see your disk there, then maybe your disk is dead and you need to try to repair or replace.

If you can see your disk there, then try accessing to Disk Management and check if you can see the drive, and the letter for this drive is available or is conflicting.

Comment: Did you see the pictures I linked?
Should they show there?

Comment: Yes, I´m and I could only see just one HD. You should check to which HD corresponds and check if the HD is physically running when you are reboorting the laptop. If you can listen any noise... maybe you´ve a mechanical failure.